# X64dbg is not loading program expected address space (Not same as Ghidra shows)

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ghidra, x64dbg

I have this code written in "Visual studio community edition" in main.cpp and built a release version called `Test.exe`

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    i++;
    std::string s;

    std::cout << "Hello World" << i << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Hello World1" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << s  << std::endl;
}
```

When I load it up in Ghidra the `0x140001290` but when load same binary in x64dbg I see the address `0x00007FF777311290` see picture [image]

here are the threads (just incase)
[image]

Update:
Added file that show link to main.cpp:
[image]

Here is the code with rows:
[image]

**Question:**
How come these addresses are diffrent in Ghidra compare to x64dbg?

Comment: They are not stopped at the same code.  Left shows it at main(), right shows it at the C runtime initialization code.  The true start address of a program built with MSVC++.  Which eventually calls main().

Comment: How to get to address 0x140001290? In Options->Preferences have only "entry breakpoint*" Im not avabile to break at it. But thought this was same address just that it was loaded into memory at wrong place.

Comment: because aslr. Ghidra show address based on `ImageBase` from `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64` and windows relocated PE to random base

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips about ASLR  (Address space layout randomization). I found this video that explains way of turning it off
https://youtu.be/DGX7oZvdmT0  I will test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), program will be loaded into randomized base address.

Here are some tips to overcome the problem that x64dbg and Ghidra showing different address:

- If you are using VisualStudio to compile the program, use [`/DYNAMICBASE:NO`](https://web.archive.org/web/20230421083236/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase-use-address-space-layout-randomization?view=msvc-170) linker option to disable ASLR
- Use PE viewer/editor like [PE Bear](https://github.com/hasherezade/pe-bear) to remove `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE` (0x40) attribute from `OptionalHdr.DllCharacteristics` ([PE Bear showing OptionalHdr.DllCharacteristics having IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsrV1.png))
- Disable ASLR system-wide (Method might be different across Windows versions)
- Use plugin like [ret-sync](https://github.com/bootleg/ret-sync) to synchronize cursor between reverse engineering tools
- Rebase image base address in the Ghidra [[ref](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/1020#issuecomment-532357102)]
- Calculate address manually